# Displaying HTML content inside a TextView without its tags

Tags: java, android, html

I have a string

`<p>Speed is what defines us.</p>  <p>The adrenaline starts pumping when you put your foot through the pedal and shift into top gear. It may not be viable to do the same on the road outside, but why limit the desire when the virtual world comes calling? Give birth to the speedster which lay dormant in you and leave your competition abarf.</p>  <h1>Game Version</h1>  <p>Need For Speed Most Wanted v1.3 English version.</p>  <h1>General Rules </h1>  <p>1st Round will be a time trial where every player will be given 2 laps of Campus Way.</p>`

I want to parse this string and display the styled text in a textView without the tags.

i have used `txtDisply.setText(Html.fromHtml(myString))` but this displays the text as it is i.e tags included.It does not style the text.  help!!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried casting the Html to Spanned? Ie. Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml(text); textView.setText(sp);

Comment: replace the tags using String.replace()

Comment: but i want to style the text

Comment: if you really want to style a Text then used `WebView` and load `CSS` on it